# Heroku Rake and Heroku Push Not Working - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

If i try running: heroku rake db:migrate, this is the error i get:

```
rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
/app/config/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>
```

Running: git push heroku master i get this:

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have tried adding: config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false to application.rb but it did not help :(.

This app i'm trying to push used to be on heroku, but i accidentally deleted my herokuapp. Please help!

Comment: What's your `config.eager_load` setting?

Comment: config.eager_load = true

Comment: Try setting it to `config.eager_load = true if config.eager_load.nil?`

Comment: rolify was the problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Rolify, new version has problems so I had to step down back to 3.2.0.